# Azure Application Insights Profiler data is not shown on Profiler blade

Tags: azure, azure-web-apps, azure-app-services, application-insights

I have an Azure App Services web app with an Application Insights extension enabled (not in the app codebase, just injected via the Azure portal).
I can see the analytics in Application Insights section of an app and in the associated Application Insights instance as well.
I have disabled the default continuous web job (ApplicationInsightsProfiler2) in order to create my own with the custom schedule (in fact, triggered when it is required) according to [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-profiler#manual-installation) link.

However, when I run this web job (and can see it's progress\status as successful in WebJob blade or even in Kudu), the Profiler blade in Application Insights saying always "Profiler is stopped."
[image: AppInsights Profiler]

How can I deal with it to see the results of my profiling?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?